# OpenStreeMap: export a place's boundaries

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson, boundaries

I'd like to export the boundaries (perimeter) of a place. For instance, consider the boundaries of the University of Illinois at Chicago at [this link](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/210649421).

I see it's pretty easy to export an OSM file. But how can I export only that red line (perimeter)?

I don't need a script to do that, even a manual solution would be fine. I tried to navigate the UI for quite a time, but I couldn't find a way.

My ultimate goal is to convert the boundaries to a GeoJson.

Comment: Hi, interesting, not sure if this can do it https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Export

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Overpass API for this.

Go to https://overpass-turbo.eu and enter the following script:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
way(210649421);
out geom;
```

The way-Id was taken from your link.
Then click on `Run`.

Afterwards, you can switch to the `Data` tab in the top right and copy the JSON for this area.

Alternatively, you can also use Export -> "raw data directly from Overpass API" to directly download a JSON payload, bypassing the browser output. For GeoJSON output, use Export -> "download/copy as GeoJSON" instead.